# opening non-extension file with os.path.join

Tags: python, file, python-os

I might be missing a small thing but not really sure how to get rid of the problem.

Having a directory `Pic_checker`. In this directory I have:

```
Pic_checker
  --setup.py
  /src
    --app.py
  /dir_with_doc
    --doc
```

`setup.py` with `entry_points={"console_scripts": ["pbl=app:main"]}` bcs I wanna run it just by typing `pbl`

`src` directory with `app.py` with `main` function.

`dir_with_doc` directory with `doc` file - this file has no extension.

In this `main` function I have:

```
with open(
    os.path.join(__file__, "../../dir_with_doc/doc"),
    encoding="utf-8",
) as f:
```

Bcs I want to run the script with only `pbl` command in terminal, I need to either put aboslute paths (I don't like this) or put relative path to the app.py file with `__file__` in the `os.path.join` function and navigate. Sadly getting error:

```
print(os.path.join(__file__, "../../dir_with_doc/doc"))

# /home/user/Pic_checker/src/app.py/../../dir_with_doc/doc
```

`NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: /home/user/Pic_checker/src/app.py/../../dir_with_doc/doc`.

I tried opening `os.path.join` thing earlier (with `configparser.Configparser().read()` on windows) and it was working with regular files so I assume problem is with the extension (?) and my question is:

**How do I make the nonextension file suitable for it? Or is there another way of reading nonextension `doc` file relatively to the script file? Or am I missing a small detail?**

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is in the `open` function not in the `os.path.join` I think

Comment: You need to remove the `app.py` part from `__FILE__` before it's something valid to use with `os.path.join()`.

Comment: @Aelius what exactly do you mean?

Comment: The `os.path.join` function is only a smart string manipulator function: it doesn't check if the strings that you pass to it really exist, you could try with a totally invented path and you can see that the function will work properly without no error

Comment: you should follow the advice of @jasonharper . Maybe you could try to do a path expansion of what produced by the `os.path.join` function with the `glob` module. Something like `glob.glob(os.path.join(your_path))`

Comment: @Aelius I probably got confused bcs much eariler I tried `self.config.read(os.path.join(__file__, "..\..\conf\conf.ini"))` and it was working properly (on win machine). Now I can see the `Configparser()` and `open()` works a little differently and I was looking for a problem where it is not. I'll take a look at `glob`. Thanks!

Comment: @Leemosh Instead of using `glob` I've seen that there is an easier function in the `os` module: `os.path.realpath()`, I will put this in my answer

Comment: @Aelius that is exactly what I found few mins ago as well. Yeah, that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that to get that working you should translate the path produced from the `os.path.join` function in a complete existing path expanding the `..` symbol that are interpretated literally instead. You can use the [`os.path.realpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) function. So try this:

```
with open(
    os.path.realpath(os.path.join(__file__, "../../dir_with_doc/doc")),
    encoding="utf-8",
) as f:
```

Comment: I managed to create a little different solution, but I'm sure yours is gonna work as well. Thanks for helping me out ^^

Comment: Yes I've seen, that will work too. Happy to have helped

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to go.

```
with open(
    f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))}/../dir_with_doc/doc"
)
```